# Is there a better formula to utilize when Customer both creates and edit the record at the same time?​

Tags: workflow

I have written this rule.

```
ISCHANGED ( Customer_Address_Reviewed__c ) || 
ISCHANGED ( Credit_Card_Form_submited_SalesOps__c ) || 
ISCHANGED ( Tax_Exempt_Status_submitted_to_Sales_Ops__c)
```

This alert is not always triggering. Is there a better formula to utilize when Customer both creates and edit the record at the same time?​[image]

Comment: Have you noticed when this is not firing?

Comment: Hi Reshma,

It is not firing, it is saving and editing records every time I try to edit that field in the existing record and also new records..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OR() in your Rule . Hopefully it will work.

```
OR(ISCHANGED(Amount), 
ISCHANGED( CloseDate ), 
ISCHANGED( Name ) 
)
```

[image]